# redis-cli: How to change the output delimiter to the NUL character?

Tags: database, redis, redis-cli

I like to get the members of a set, `NUL`-separated. What do I do?

```
redis-cli SMEMBERS theset
```

Uses the newline delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `python` as a workaround:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

first = True
for mem in r.smembers(sys.argv[1]):
    if not first:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\0")

    sys.stdout.buffer.write(mem)
    first = False
```